# PHP - Weird issue with POST data

Tags: php, post

I'm coding out a simple contact form, and the following code is giving me trouble:

```
if(!strlen($_POST['lastname']) > 0){
    echo '<p class="message error">Please enter the parent\'s last name.</p>';
}

if(!strlen($_POST['comments']) > 5){
    echo '<p class="message error">Please tell us a little more in the comments field.</p>';
}
```

Relevant form element:

```
<textarea name="comments" cols="60" rows="5"><?=(isset($_POST['comments']) ? $_POST['comments'] : '')?></textarea>
```

When I leave both fields blank, only the first error message (along with the others not shown) displays, whereas the one for the comments field does not.

The error checking even returns with an error if I submit the comments fields with less than 5 characters, as it should, but the error message does not print. In addition, I even echoed the strlen() of the comments field when I submitted with it blank and it prints out 0.

Can anyone see what the problem here is?

Comment: Why not use if(strlen($_POST['comments']) < 6){ - it reads better.

Comment: @Kieran Andrews - Because I'm 2 hours into overtime tonight, that's why, hehe... But thanks for that.
Repost as answer please.

Comment: Classic case of *don't drink and code*, or *don't get tired and code*. :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if (!strlen > 0)` first evaluates `strlen`, which gives, say, 10. This is then negated by `!` to `false`. *This* is then compared to `> 0`, which is `false`, since `false` will be cast to `0` and `0 > 0` is `false`. The other way around, if the string is actually empty, the condition will be `true`.

You either want `if (!(strlen > 0))` or `if (strlen <= 0)`.

Answer (score 3):

Missing parenthesis?

```
if(!(strlen($_POST['lastname']) > 0)) {
    echo '<p class="message error">Please enter the parent\'s last name.</p>';
}

if(!(strlen($_POST['comments']) > 5)) {
    echo '<p class="message error">Please tell us a little more in the comments field.</p>';
}
```

Comment: Tied with deceze... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate the data whether it is entered  you can use following options too

```
if(empty($_POST['name'])){
  echo 'Enter Name';
}

or

if(trim($_POST['name'])==''){
 echo 'Enter Name';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, the problem here is that the ! applies to the return value from strlen only and not the entire comparison expression.  The above if statements will *always* return false.

It could be rewritten like this to work:

```
if (!(strlen($_POST['lastname']) > 0)){ /* display error */ }
```

This is because the ! negates the result of the expression nested in parentheses and not the number returned by strlen.

Also, I would recommend not returning the POSTed value unaltered in the HTML source, that's just asking for trouble...